# Nodejs website hosted in AWS Linux EC2 Instance. performance issues 3rd party api invoke with DNS endpoint

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

We have built one micro portal in node js and hosted in AWS Linux EC2 instance. In portal we are invoking 3rd party api. We are facing performance ( response delay) issue   while invoking api endpoint  with DNS. we do not have any performance ( response issue) issue with same endpoint using IP address. Can any one help us, how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update the name servers on your ec2 machine that are being used for dns.

Maybe this will help:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf